# Zakat need to pay

Tags: zakat

Assalam Alaikum

I and my wife both are working. I don't have any saving from last one year, although my wife has, so do I need to pay *Zakat* on behalf of my wife or *Zakat* need to be paid from my wife savings?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [Would the Zakat be applicable to both the husband and wife's gold?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16329/would-the-zakat-be-applicable-to-both-the-husband-and-wifes-gold?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Zakat is paid per person not as a family. Your wife has to pay her Zakat not you if she had enough savings money for Zakat. Same applies for you.

Please refer to the answer in this question:

[Would the Zakat be applicable to both the husband and wife's gold?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16329/would-the-zakat-be-applicable-to-both-the-husband-and-wifes-gold/24621#24621)